# “your heart just shrank” vs. “your heart just shrunk”

Tags: american-english, british-english, past-participles, simple-past

If I say:

> Your heart just shrank two sizes too small.

Is the verb shrank correct as is? Or should it be in participle form?

> Your heart just shrunk two sizes too small.

Which one would be correct in these two cases?

Comment: Regardless of *shrank* vs. *shrunk*, you can't tack on a "too small" like this. Something can *shrink two sizes*, or it can *shrink so it becomes two sizes too small*, but you can't load both "two sizes" and "too small" onto the verb all at once.

Comment: @Martha Sure you can. *"I put the knit sweater in the washer to pre-shrink it but I accidentally used hot water instead of warm, so it shrank two sizes too small."* It only works when the intention is to shrink it, but only to a certain size. (This may not be what the OP wants, of course.) It's a similar structure to *"The taxi drove us two blocks too far, so we didn't leave a tip."*

Comment: This question can be improved by researching before you post the question, including the results of your research in the question, and explaining how those results were inadequate to answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would normally use the past tense.   There is no auxiliary there.

However, there is historic confusion about whether the past of ***shrink*** is supposed to be ***shrank*** or ***shrunk***. *Shrunk* as the past dominated through the 18<sup>th</sup> century, and remained common during the 19<sup>th</sup> century;  it still survives today as a minority alternative to *shrank*.  Sir Walter Scott used *shrunk* in *Ivanhoe* and in *Betrothed*, both during the 19<sup>th</sup> century, and you have but to consider the 1989 film, *Honey, I Shrunk the Kids*, as one modern example of people  using *shrunk* instead of *shrank* as the past for *shrink*.

That means that both your examples can be generated by native speakers, although some may think one or the other of those two sounds funny to them. Saying *“he shrunk something”* instead of *“he shrank something”* might seem to have a certain rustic sound to it today, but it has a long history.  It might be best to avoid in formal writing except for related speech, as many people think only of *shrank* for the past form of the verb, and so it might be perceived as a careless error.

Writers who used *shrunk* for the past often used ***shrunken*** for the past participle; Scott is one example of such.  Today, however, the longer *shrunken* participle form is now usually reserved for adjectival uses, although it can still occasionally be found causatively, as in *“to have shrunken his head”* as opposed to *“his trousers have shrunk”*.   (There was once an corresponding causative, *to **shrench** something*, that went along with the non-causative *to shrink*, but which is now obsolete.  This *shrink/shrench* pair followed the same model as *drink/drench* and *stink/stench*.)

This sort of variation between which one is the past and which the past participle is particularly common with strong verbs that have a vowel change from *i* to *u* in them, such as *sing/sang/sung*, which once used *sung* as the past. Similarly,  *sunk* long served as the past of *sink*, and Johnson in the 18<sup>th</sup> century called it the normal form, ascribing to *sank* the label “anciently”.  Indeed, the OED allows either *sank* or *sunk* for the past, and it allows either *sunk* or *sunken* as the past participle. With *stink*, using *stunk* for the past persisted through the 19<sup>th</sup> century before settling down to modern *stank* and *had stunk*.  The common *drink/drank/drunk/drunken* has a similarly checkered past.

The OED gives as the etymology of ***shrink*** the following:

> **Etymology**: OE. *scrincan* (pa. t. *scranc, scruncon,* pa. pple. *ʒescruncen*) = MDutch *schrinken* (only in Kilian as obs. Flem.; ? from Eng.), Sw. *skrynka* to wrinkle (MSw. *skrunkin* pa. pple. shrivelled, wrinkled), Norw. *skrekka, skrøkka* (pa. t. *skrakk, skrokk,* pa. pple. *skrokken, skrokket*). The causative is **shrench** *v.<sup>1</sup>*
>
> The pa. t. originally had vowel change *I shrank, we shrunke(n*, but, as early as the 14<sup>th</sup> c., the properly plural form is found with a singular subject, and *shronk, shrunk* becomes frequent in the 15<sup>th</sup> c.; *shrunk* is the normal pa. t. in the 18<sup>th</sup> c., and still survives. The pa. pple. *shrunken* is now rarely employed in conjugation with the vb. ‘to have’; see also **shrunk, shrunken.**

Comment: Exactly. This has nothing to do with _just_.