# "sunk" or "sunken"?

Tags: adjectives, past-participles, conjugation, copular-verbs, inflections

> The boat lies half-sunken in the bay.

*Sunken* is an adjective, right? But in the previous sentence, it seems to be acting as adverb modifying *lies*.

Should the sentence be:

> The boat lies half sunk in the bay.

Comment: I think both are correct.

Comment: *sunken* is an older form of the past participle of *sink*, now more commonly *sunk*. Both are acceptable. I can't explain why, but *half-sunken* sounds better to my British ears in that context.

Comment: @TrevorD It’s because it’s an adjective. *Sink* and *drink* can both be fit into a four-form inflection model, where the fourth version is reserved for adjectival use. See my answer.

Comment: For variant inflections of the similar *drink* and *shrink*, see also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/81223 and http://english.stackexchange.com/q/70343.

Answer (score 20):

You seem to be asking two different questions.

## *Of Copular Complements*

The first is how an adjective like *half-sunken* can apply to a verb in your sentence. The answer is that it doesn’t, because *lie* is here functioning more like a [copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_copulae). It just serves to link the subject with a predicate description of that subject.  Some writers prefer the term “semi-copula” for the verbs other than *be* that work this way, especially since many of them can also work as non-copulas.  But here are similar examples of verbs that take (or can take) adjectives in their complements:

- The milk had gone bad already.
- He’s sittin’ pretty.
- Make sure it lies flat.
- That seems unlikely.
- That looks pretty good.
- They left still hungry.
- In the end it proved impossible.
- I ended up looking pretty good.

So the use in your cited sentence is perfectly correct as an adjective complement of *lie*.

---

## *Of Shrunken Heads*

Your second question appears to revolve around whether the past participle of *sink* is *sunken* or *sunk*.   The answer is that either will serve.  Like many strong verbs, *sink* has enjoyed a range of possible historical inflections, and there still remains some ambiguity today.

In general, *sink* inflects like *drink* and *shrink*, which all enjoy, or can enjoy, a four-fold paradigm:

- *drink, drank, drunk, drunken*
- *sink, sank, sunk, sunken*
- *shrink, shrank, shrunk, shrunken*

Where the fourth form is reserved for adjectival uses, as in a *drunken man*, a *sunken ship*, or a *shrunken head*.

That’s the way I myself personally inflect those verbs, but that’s just one model, and different speakers say different things at different times. In one common alternate model, we see this progression instead, which lacks an *-ank* form in the preterite and does not distinguish verbal from adjectival uses of the last form:

- *drink, drunk, drunken*
- *sink, sunk, sunken*
- *shrink, shrunk, shrunken*

For *drink*, that alternate model is now considered non-standard, but for the other two, the case is less clear, and both models have some currency and acceptance. Think of the movie title [*Honey, I Shrunk the Kids*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey,_I_Shrunk_the_Kids), or the old boardgame’s commercial’s [“You sunk my battleship!”](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJo1WVTjaB0)  That shows that the alternate model still lives for *shrink* and *sink*, even though saying “I ***drunk** a lot last night” is now considered thoroughly non-standard, as too is “I hadn’t ***drank** much that night.”

For *sink*, the OED gives the past tense as **either** *sank* **or** *sunk*, and the past participle as **either** *sunk* **or** *sunken*.  It gives *sinken* as a vestigial dialect use of an older form, and reports that the weak inflection *sinked* was also sometimes found, albeit rarely except in one now-obsolete circumstance.

In some speakers, there may be a difference in transitive and intransitive uses:

- The ship **sank** off the coast of Galicia.
- He **sunk** his own ship rather than allow pirates to board it.

Comment: This is a truly interesting answer. I'm led to wonder if choosing the inflection is at all influenced by the verb's transitivity. That is, "to sink" has transitive and intransitive uses; think of "I sank/sunk into the water" versus "You sank/sunk my battleship."  I'm also curious if British and American versions of the Battleship commercials might have used different forms.  Time to check YouTube!

Answer (score 8):

The OED states that ‘In present usage [*sunk*] in adjectival use tends to be restricted to senses implying deliberate human agency’.

As we don’t know that that is the case in your example, *sunken* seems appropriate.

Comment: There are three strong *-ink* verbs in English: *drink, sink, shrink*.  In modern use, the *-unken* forms for these tend only to be used as adjectives, not as verbal past participles.  So we still sometimes have *drunken men* even though we would never now say that they **had drunken.* Similarly for *sunken ships* and *shrunken heads*.